# Linq left outer join and group by issue

Tags: linq, group-by, left-join

Hi All my following query returns results like this:

```
lstView.DataSource = (from h in context.HolidayMains
                              join hd in context.HolidayDetails  on h.Id equals hd.HolidayMainId into hd2
                              from hd in hd2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join e in context.Employees on h.CreatedBy equals e.Id into e2
                              from e in e2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              join o in context.OfficeLocations on hd.OfficeLocation equals o.Id into o2
                              from o in o2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new
                              {
                                  h.HolidayTitle,
                                  h.Date,
                                  OfficeLocation = o.Name,
                                  CreatedBy = e.Name,
                                  h.Id
                              }).ToList();
```

[image]

But I need result like this :

[image]

How it can be done?

Comment: You just need to use `GroupBy` to group your list into items of the same name/date.

Comment: group x by new { x.Column1, x.Column2 }